# Как отправить пост запрос на чужой сайт?

Tags: javascript, http, post

Как отправить пост запрос на чужой сайт при помощи js? С помощью curl php смог отправить, а вот js не могу, т.к дает ошибку кросс

Comment: Может быть всё-таки CORS?

Comment: Что за ошибку вы получаете?

Comment: Скорее всего, вы имели ввиду не "кросс", а CORS.
Если по-простому, клиенты (браузеры) реализуют механизм CORS для безопасности пользователя, дабы ограничить воздействие вредоносных ссылок и скриптов на странице с помощью заголовков.
Отсюда же и ограничения отправки запросов из браузера с помощью JS. Curl PHP запускается не из браузера, потому и CORS на него не действует. Если нужно получить данные с чужого API на страницу - можно поднять сервер и обратиться уже к нему со страницы

Comment: Подробнее про CORS [тут](https://medium.com/nuances-of-programming/%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BF%D1%8C%D1%8E%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%83%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B3%D0%BB%D1%8F%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%BE-cors-20a97786c18c) и [тут](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS)